# How can I merge,Join row cells that have same values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame;

[image]

I would like to merge the cells that contain the same values in the concurrent rows and also join the first field to one cell. An output that I am after based on this is

[image]

I have tried a few Groupby options but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby multiple columns, then aggregate the matching Field 1 into a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field 1':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],'Field 2':[1, 1, 2, 1], 'Field 3': [2, 2, 3, 12], 'Field 4': [3, 3, 4, 13]})

dfg = df.groupby(['Field 2', 'Field 3', 'Field 4'], as_index=False).agg({
    'Field 1': lambda x : ', '.join(sorted(list(x)))  })
```

to get dfg:

```
   Field 2  Field 3  Field 4 Field 1
0        1        2        3    A, B
1        1       12       13       B
2        2        3        4       A
```